# Conventional package structuring for an API

Tags: java, software-design

If I intend to create a set of API that will allow other developers to interact with my application, how should I structure this set of API in the sense of packaging?

I am considering this...
For all the classes that runs my actual application, I have them in com.app.core
So for all features of my actual application, I have them in com.app.core.products, com.app.core.events, com.app.core.views, com.app.core.accounts, etc.

Then subsequently for the set of API classes, I put them in com.app.events, com.app.accounts, com.app.utils, etc.

Is this a good practise?

I've found this very weird in a few ways. 
First, the core package is open to all. People can still access the core package objects directly, bypassing the  API.

Second, I am having repetitive packages both in the 'core' package and in the outer package which serves as the API packages. For instance, com.app.core.accounts consists of all the classes the main application uses to operate its accounts module and com.app.accounts is an set of API classes for other developers to work from.

Third, if having repetitive packages is fine and is the right way to do so, then why wouldn't I simply let anyone access directly to the com.app.core package and I don't have repetitive folders and also the core package is accessible anyway?

What could have been a better way to do this? I working in Java and pretty new to this idea of creating my own API.

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of application you are building? It might be advisable to split it based on the application layers: data access, business logic, UI.

Comment: I am building some kind of POS system. Did you mean I could have them like in com.app.views, com.app.model, com.app.controllers. And then these packages will be both the core and API packages?

Comment: In our subdivision we usually creating two Eclipse projects for an application: framework and UI. Structure of the UI project is controlled by the UI framework we use. Structure of the "meat" project is such that there are package subtrees com.company.application.data, com.company.application.service, com.company.application.process (for background processes) and some misc. packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion those 'repetitive' packages are not a problem. They are just packages after all. The developer that works with your API only only sees them.

Also it's not necessarily a problem that the developer can access your implementation classes. It's the same with Java itself: There are a lot of `com.sun` classes that can be used but that doesn't mean that you should. It makes porting to another Java runtime difficult.

It also depends a bit on the project. If you work with an architecture that cleanly separates the API from the implementation, the user of your API can't access the implementation. OSGi and Web services come to mind. In this case you can create two different libraries: the implementation and the API with the implementation depending on the API. The API contains all classes that are important for external users. That way separation is quite easy.

The third problem doesn't really exist. You can have different libraries that provide classes for the same packages. As long as you control the namespace and don't have duplicate classes in the same package everything is fine. A package is just a name, nothing else.

Comment: Do I create them as separate projects if I want to create them as two different libraries? Also, how should implementation depending on the API? The way I thought was to have the API depending on the implementation.

Comment: No, the core depends on the API. That way you can give the API to other developers without having to give them the core.

Comment: hmm...Since an API is somewhat a higher level interface for other developers, wouldn't the API has to depend on a core for itself to be considered higher level? Also, if a core depends on the API, if I want to make changes to my system, where should I edit from: core or API?

Comment: I don't know if an API should be considered higher or lower than anything. Ideally your API should be as stable as possible and allow for internal changes in your core (bug fixing, performance improvements and the like). Changes in the API should happen at defined moments in time (the release).

Answer (score 0):

I usually create two different (eclipse) projects for these kind of scenarios. One project contains the core, and that other project contains the api/interface-classes. The core project is dependent on the api project.

I use the same package names in both projects. The two projects are built to two different jars, and the api jar is given to the clients / developers who need to access (or write plugins) for my application/system. The jars are usually named e.g. myapplication.jar and myapplication_api.jar

Comment: Say when another developer makes use of your API, he imports your API package. And then he also has to import the core project package since the API is dependant on it but just that he is accessing from the API and not the core package classes. Would there be a problem in the package path when importing them since they both have similar package names?

Comment: The user of my API should not access my classes directly, and no, there's no problem in having the same package in several jar files.

Comment: For example, if your core implementations are in an Eclipse project call Project_1 and your APIs are in Project_2. Since Project_2 APIs are dependant on Project_1, the classes in Project_2 needs to import classes from Project_1. But how is this possible since they are separate Eclipse projects?

Comment: No, the API is not dependent on the Core. The Core project is dependent on the API. That is the API contains interfaces and some classes, and Core contains implementations and the rest of the classes. Eclipse projects can declare dependencies to other Eclipse projects.